# ASP.NET UserManager.FindByEmailAsync returns null even though the user exists in the db

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

So the title is self explanatory
below you can find the code for the login endpoint and the user Repository
i've tried to register multiple users and login with them but FindByEmail returns null for all of them
i'm using MSSQL if that helps at all

```
 [HttpPost("login")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserLoginDto userDto)
        {
            var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByEmail(userDto.Email);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized("Invalid username or password.");
            }

            var passwordIsValid = await _userRepository.CheckPassword(user, userDto.Password);

            if (!passwordIsValid)
            {
                return Unauthorized("Invalid username or password.");
            }

            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var token = GenerateJwtToken(user, user.TenantId.ToString(), userRoles);

            return Ok(new { token });
        }

        private string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user, string tenantId, IList<string> roles)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSecret);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim("TenantId", tenantId),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, string.Join(",", roles))
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
```

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUserByEmail(string email)
        {
            return await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        }
```

it's also worth noting that I'm using CreateAsync to create my users since I've seen that creating the user directly with EF core can cause this problem but that's not the case here

Comment: Could you please tell me your application is asp.net identity or the asp.net core identity?

Comment: I'm using Identity Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i think i know now why this was happening , i had a query filter on the User entity to filter by tenantID like that
 `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasQueryFilter(u => u.TenantId == CurrentTenantId);`

and that was causing the FindbyEmail to filter based on users without a tenantID somehow since I was fetching the CurrentTenantId from the current Logged in user which in my case there wasn't any because this check was done for the login endpoint

so I created a custom attribute to handle this and used it as global filter for all of my entities, and maybe creating another dB context just to handle authentication would have been a valid approach but that's a question for another day